# Why are two arguments provided when I call a parent class method in Python

Tags: python, django

I am trying to call the cleanse method from ParentSerializer but from the ChildSerializer as seen in the last line.

```
class ParentSerializer(models.ModelSerializer):
    def cleanse(self):
        if hasattr(self, 'initial_data'):
            val1 = self.initial_data['name']
            val2 = self.initial_data['age']
            val3 = self.initial_data['city']
        return self.initial_data

class ChildSerializer(GenericSerializer):
    def is_valid(self, raise_exception=False):
        if hasattr(self, 'initial_data'):
            super(ChildSerializer, self).cleanse(self)
```

error:

```
TypeError: cleanse() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 1):

Replace your final line with

```
super(ChildSerializer, self).cleanse()
```

You don't need self, super call refers to your parent class and acts as it.